# AT modem command, how to detect frequency sent from a call

Tags: linux, modem, minicom

I am trying to use AT modem commands to call a phone number, receive a kissoff tone (at 1400 hz frequency), send 12 dtmf ones, and receive a handshake tone (different pure tone frequency)

I know how to send the DTmf tones but do not know how to identify any frequencies that are sent over the phone line.

Is there a command for this or does minicom do this automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. You just tell the modem to dial, and the negotiations are part of the firmware and the protocol it wants to use to communitcate,_e.g._ V.32bis. I don't think you can use it as a generic analog to digital receiver/sampler.

Comment: IIRC some modems used to be able to identify in-band DTMF so i wouldn't say never just yet